# Listary for Mac

Tags: applications

I use the **Listary** software everyday (most of the time) when I use Windows. Its features are

- find folder and files as you type (in the current folder)
- smart commands like *open this directory in command prompt*
- access **Listary** from anywhere
- favorite and recent file and folder from anywhere
- support (of above features) for various application

You can see the features in action in this [Listary features video screencast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fi3HFOJTYAY).

[Alternativeto.net](http://alternativeto.net/software/listary/?platform=mac) does not give any interesting alternative for mac.

I would like to know is there any app out there like that one for Mac?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://alternativeto.net/software/listary/?platform=mac, in particular [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) and [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/).

Comment: You should first see the video link I provided first. Listary feature is different from Alfred, Quicksilver and LaunchBar.

Comment: @TunWN I took the time to watch the video. As there are no "generic Windows lists" on the Mac, no Mac app will support them. Apart from this, all suggestions from MrMage are useful and fulfill the criteria you named -- the actual workflows may be a bit different though.

Comment: Thanks @myhd, Alfred & LaunchBar are just as Listary for Windows. Excellents recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

[Orange](https://github.com/naaive/orange) is suitable, it's a cross-platform file search tool.

Comment: It may be cross-plattform, but at least the page you link seems to lack any details on how to install this on macOS (and the link in the Build section is broken). Can you expand your answer a bit to show how this can be done?